# How to identify the most likely correct timestamp in a sequence of events with missing or duplicated timestamps?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate, heuristics

I have a dataset that records the handling of police calls-for-service. The dataset has six columns: incident_id, unit_id, timestamp_dispatched, timestamp_responding, timestamp_arrived, and timestamp_clearing_scene. The four timestamp columns have to be in chronological order as they always occur in sequence. However, not all timestamps are recorded appropriately, and some are missing or duplicated. Specifically, I have 15% missing values in timestamp_responding and 35% missing values in timestamp_arrived. Also, all four timestamps are sometimes logged double or triple, which could be due to mistakes or other reasons (e.g., arriving at the wrong scene first).

Also, there are two procedures that will introduce bias in my data. The dispatch centre system only clears calls if three out of four statusses are logged. As a result, if a unit only logs dispatch (say at 12:00) and cleared_scene (say at 13:00) - their handling doesn't get archived in the system. In order resolve this, dispatcher (say at 14:00) log either *responding* or *arrived* (or both) and subsequently log *cleared-scene* again (otherwise *cleared* predates *responding* or *arrived* which the system also doesn't allow. In reality, the incident took an hour, and we are ignorant of the response and arrival time. However, in our data the data now appear to have lasted 2 hours, with it taking 2 hours to start responding, and then just half a sec to arrive and clear the call. I hope to filter out the procedural mistake as well.

The second procedure is that *responds*, *arrival*, and *cleared* (or a combination of two of these) are statussed within like 2 seconds of eachother by the dispatcher or the officer on the street. In this case, only the latest logging really means anything and should be kept.

I want to find a heuristic to identify the most likely correct timestamp to use in my analysis. I have reasons to believe that for timestamp_dispatched the last logged timestamp is usually correct and for timestamp_clearing_scene the first timestamp is usually correct. The four subsequent timestamps should adhere to my assumptions as much as possible, but should always meet the criteria that they occur in sequence. So:

timestamp_dispatched < timestamp_responding < timestamp_arrived < timestamp_clearing_scene

Here's a reproducible example of my dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

# Generate sample data
data <- data.frame(
  incident_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  unit_id = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
  timestamp_dispatched = c('2022-01-01 12:00:00', '2022-01-01 12:05:00', '2022-01-01 12:10:00', '2022-01-01 12:15:00', '2022-01-01 12:20:00', '2022-01-01 12:25:00'),
  timestamp_responding = c('2022-01-01 12:01:00', NA, '2022-01-01 12:12:00', '2022-01-01 12:16:00', NA, '2022-01-01 12:26:00'),
  timestamp_arrived = c('2022-01-01 12:02:00', '2022-01-01 12:06:00', '2022-01-01 12:13:00', NA, '2022-01-01 12:22:00', NA),
  timestamp_clearing_scene = c('2022-01-01 12:20:00', '2022-01-01 12:30:00', '2022-01-01 12:40:00', NA, '2022-01-01 12:50:00', NA)
)

# Convert timestamps to datetime format
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("timestamp"), ymd_hms))

# Drop rows where incident_id and unit_id are duplicated
data <- data %>% 
  distinct(incident_id, unit_id, .keep_all = TRUE)
```